# What port number does SOAP use?

Tags: soap, port

What is the default port number that the SOAP protocol works on?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is no such thing as "SOAP protocol".  SOAP is an XML schema.

It usually runs over HTTP (port 80), however.

Comment: Isn't the P in SOAP "protocol" ;) ?

Comment: @nonnb: Aye, good point :) However, the "S" stands for "simple", and that's blatantly false too.

Comment: so then in the wsdl document if no port number is mentioned then does it mean that you should use port 80 to communicate with the webservice ?

Comment: @user: any time you see "http://something.com/file.ext", with no port, it implies port 80. "https" with no port implies port 443.

Comment: @DavidW - i am sure you know SOAP was called Simple Object Access Protocol.... So one really could call it a protocol if one wished.... Its all semantics - really!

Comment: I can't believe I said SOAP is not a protocol! February must have been a bad month.  I meant it's not a transport protocol, yeah, that's what I meant ;-)

Comment: SOAP is a protocol, and "SOAP Message" is what you said @skaffman. https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383486

Answer (score 11):

SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol) is the communication protocol in the web service scenario.

One benefit of SOAP is that it allowas RPC to execute through a firewall. But to pass through a firewall, you will probably want to use 80.
it uses **port no.8084**
To the firewall, a SOAP conversation on 80 looks like a POST to a web page. However, there are extensions in SOAP which are specifically aimed at the firewall. In the future, it may be that firewalls will be configured to filter SOAP messages. But as of today, most firewalls are SOAP ignorant.

so exclusively open SOAP Port in Firewalls

Answer (score 2):

SOAP (communication protocol) for communication between applications.
Uses  HTTP  (port 80) or SMTP ( port 25 or 2525 ), for message negotiation and transmission.