# What is PHP SoapClient port?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

$client = new SoapClient("http://www.mobilywebservices.com:86/SMSWebService/SMSIntegration.asmx?wsdl");

What is PHP SoapClient port because my local network used firewall and closed all ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP is an XML schema.

It usually runs over HTTP (port 80), however.

Use the search: [What port number does SOAP use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861545/what-port-number-does-soap-use)

Also mentioned in the thread: it uses port no.8084 To the firewall,

The URL `http://www.mobilywebservices.com:86/SMSWebService/SMSIntegration.asmx?wsdl`

you are trying to connect to has `:86` behind it so it uses `port 86` try this

**Check if SOAP is installed with** `<?php phpinfo() ?>`

Comment: I use same code on my home it's working but in my office not working i think SoapClient use internally CURL..

Comment: I just want to know firewall block communication SoapClient communication how i can enabled...

Comment: @user1838925 Sometimes it uses HTTPS Port so you could try to open it.

Comment: check my wsdl it used http not https

Comment: @user1838925 Do you get a php error message? Maybe you can add it to your question

Comment: Call to undefined method soapclient::SendSMS()
This is working 100% @ my home !

Comment: You probably don't have SOAP activated in your php office's enviroment

Comment: I already enabled from php.int also put soap dll into ext directory
i am using xampp server