# 404 error when calling Remedy from WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, remedy

I am calling Remedy from WSO2 ESB and I get the following soap error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">default backend - 404</text></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tested multiples endpoint configurations with no success. If I call the endpoint with straight forward with SoapUI I get the response, but if I go through ESB I get the error. Any help on this error?

Comment: Is your BMC endpoint is running on a container? You can enable the WIRE logs in the ESB server and verify whether the request is dispatched as expected from the ESB node. Use the following doc to enable the [WIRE Logs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Logs+in+WSO2+EI+6.6.0).

Comment: BMC endpoints is a cloud so probably it is running on a container.

Comment: Can you try enabling the WIRE logs as mentioned and cross-check the dispatched request and the direct request from the SOAP UI?

Comment: I found out that WSO2 ESB add a the port in the call but the endoint does not expect to have the port in the URL. WSO2 ESB identify the port when do the tlsv1.2 handshake and make the call using dns:port/context. How can avoid esb add the port in the call? Is that correct o the dns is not properly defined?

Answer (score 1):

ESB ports are setup in the <ESB_HOME>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Setting+Up+Host+Names+and+Ports

I don't see an option for no port, but SOAP uses 80 by default:
[What port number does SOAP use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861545/what-port-number-does-soap-use)

You can work with your BMC Helix team to setup the ports used by your servers:
https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/helixsubscriber/Network+port+configuration